# Host-local networks in Docker Compose

Tags: networking, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml, but need to model a public/private network split where the Redis instance must only be accessible to localhost.

```
version: "2.2"  # for compatibility, I can upgrade if needed
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - 8080:80
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - 6379:6379
```

This seems straightforward if I needed to restrict it to being accessible only within the docker network. Consider:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - 6379:6379
    networks:
    - backend

networks:
  frontend: {}
  backend:
    internal: true
```

However our local web developers need to be able to access that Redis instance from their host machine (outside of the docker network) when they build, run, and debug locally.

Comment: You mean "some of volunteers will run containerized redis in his machine, and other team members will be able to access that redis ?!". Is that correct ?

Comment: "Other team members will be able to access that Redis" is the scenario we want to avoid. The desired state is that every developer runs their own stack (there's lots more pieces elided here) but cannot connect to other developer's backends.

Comment: I will give you delicious answer

Comment: Check Answer below @AdamSmith . Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind the service port of redis to localhost(127.0.0.1).
Try follows...

```yaml
...
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:6379:6379
...
```

Comment: This is so trivial that I overlooked it. Thank you for the simple and straightforward solution!

Comment: :-) Good for you~

Answer (score 1):

- Run Redis Web UI called redis-commander.
- Use env vars to point to the running redis.
- Expose this new container & access it instead of exposing Redis container.

```yaml
  services:
    redis:
      # Do comment ports! no need to expose it
      # ports:
      # - 6379:6379
    // ....
    redis-commander:
      image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
        REDIS_HOST: redis:6379 # <--  Here you point to your redis
        # REDIS_PASSWORD # <- in case redis is protected with password
      ports:
        - "8081:8081"
```

Let your developers go to http://localhost:8081 and enjoy.

[Find more details about that image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rediscommander/redis-commander)